# Code working properly on JBoss 5.1, but failing on JBoss 7: wrong number of columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss5.x

The same code was working on JBoss 5.1. While trying to migrate to JBoss 7.1 I am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.domain.admin.test.User from com.domain.admin.test.TestDeskGroupPermission has the wrong number of column. should be 2
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:111)
```

My entities are below. Please note that there are no Composite primary keys.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
@Auditable
public class User extends AbstractVersionedEntity implements Serializable 
{
@Override
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long getId()
{
return super.getId();
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@XmlTransient
@Where(clause = SoftDelete.ACTIVE_JPQL)
@BatchSize(size = BATCH_DESKS)
public Set<TestDeskGroupPermission> getDeskGroupPermissions()
{
    return this.deskGroupPermissions;
}
public void setDeskGroupPermissions(final Set<TestDeskGroupPermission> deskGroupPermissions)
{
    this.deskGroupPermissions = deskGroupPermissions;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TestDeskGroupPermission")
@Auditable
public class TestDeskGroupPermission implements Serializable
{
private User                owner;
private TestGroupPermission deskGroupPermission;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "User_ID")
@XmlTransient
public User getOwner()
{
    return this.owner;
}

public void setOwner(final User owner)
{
    this.owner = owner;
}

@Embedded
@XmlTransient
public TestGroupPermission getDeskGroupPermission()
{
    return this.deskGroupPermission;
}

public void setDeskGroupPermission(final TestGroupPermission  eskGroupPermission)
{
    this.deskGroupPermission = deskGroupPermission;
}
```

}

```
@MappedSuperclass
@XmlTransient
public abstract class AbstractVersionedEntity extends AbstractBaseEntity implements VersionedEntity
{
@Override
@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@XmlTransient
public Long getId()
{
    return super.getId();
}
}
```

---

```
@MappedSuperclass
@XmlTransient
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity implements BaseEntity, Modifiable,Serializable
{
private Long id;
public AbstractBaseEntity()
{

}
@Override
@Transient
@XmlTransient
public Long getId()
{
    return this.id;
}

@Override
public void setId(final Long id)
{
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

Comment: @MappedSuperclass in AbstractVersionedEntity  is creating a problum . jboss 5.1 working proper . jboss 7.1 having issue .some one pls help me on it

Comment: Do you try to create an appropriate mapping for `private User owner;` (probably, an `@OneToOne`)? The actual mapping is doing some "default" JPA behaviour in this line. Do you change the hibernate version when you upgrade the jboss version?

Comment: No , I am using the same version which i have used earlier , If i comment it out the @ID and @Column(name = "ID") in User , I am bable to deploy the application with out the error in jboss 7.

Comment: Improve formatting and title

Comment: Remove unneed clarification since the error reporting mentions it